# Concat two populated arraylists without overwriting anything?

Tags: java

I have an arraylist which is populated (call this A). I have another arraylist, which is also populated (call this B).

A has 5 elements
B has 3 elements

Is it possible for me to add all of B's elements to A, so that B's elements start from 6 (length of A + 1), with a total of 8 elements. I am hoping to do this witout any elaborate loops but a built in method?

Also, performance wise, how bad is this sort of idea (if it is bad at all)?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the List.addAll(index,collection) method should do what you need.

At the sizes you mention this should never show a performance blip for you. Even 2 orders of magnitude larger shouldn't be an issue.

EDIT: I double checked the implementation of ArrayList.addAll(). It's about as efficient as it can be. It will do a single grow to accommodate the new elements, and it uses a System.arrayCopy to move elements.

Answer (score 1):

`List.addAll()`

Performace-wise, this is unlikely to make much impact with 5 + 3. <s>If you have much larger you could create a new `ArrayList` of the correct size first, to avoid unnecessary allocations. Alternatively, use a `LinkedList`, which will have different performance characteristics.</s>

Edit: As explained by others, `ArrayList.addAll()` is about as good as you can get.

Comment: I would strongly suggest against using LinkedList for this operation. It allocates each new node separately and appends them to the end of the list. For most sizes it would not be as efficient as ArrayList, for this particular operation. There are, of course, pathological cases, but I would stick with ArrayList.

Comment: That's true. I was thinking of a generic linked list implementation, but LinkedList doesn't work like that as you say.